# Parent Child Hierarchy in Django Model Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a serializer of a django model where in this serializer I show the parent and all the generations below.

In the model I have a field that's the "object_id" => (pk) and another field "parent_object_id" which indicates which pk is the parent:

### object_id | parent_object_id | object_name |

1000        | null                | Product       |

1001        | 1000                | Fruits        |

1002        | 1000                | Veggies       |

1003        | 1001                | Apples        |

1004        | 1001                | Bananas       |

1005        | 1003                | Variant a     |

1006        | 1003                | Variant b     |

A.Product (highest node)

1. Fruits

   1.1 Apples

   ```
   1.1.1 Variant a

   1.1.2 Variant b
   ```

   1.2 Bananas

   ```
   1.2.1 Variant x
   ```
2. Veggies

   2.1 Spinach

   ```
   2.1.1 Variant n

   2.1.2 Variant y
   ```

   2.2 Potatoes

   ```
   2.2.1 Variant c

   2.2.2 Variant g

         2.2.2.1 Some other variable

   2.2.3 Variant l
   ```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

I just can't get my head around how to achieve this.

Comment: do you have some code you could show us?

Comment: You may be interested in reading: https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/ or looking into https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html (which I think may no longer be under development)

Comment: Stephane Faroult has a whole chapter on this topic in the 'Art of SQL' if you want an excellent resource for a discussion on when to use different methods to manage hierarchy of data https://www.amazon.ca/Art-SQL-Stephane-Faroult/dp/0596008945